# ActiveStorage - retrieving file URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am migrating from deprecated [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem to `ActiveStorage` and wondering how can I get hold of attachment URL in the model (for example if I want to add it to custom `as_json` method, some elasticshearh data etc.)

Couldn't find anything in documentation for that particular use case.

Comment: I had the same problem, it seems there is no public URL for files uploaded without a private markup. With ActiveStorage all files are private by default. That is a problem for me with emails embedding images, images must be inline attached. see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719769/activestorage-for-s3-private-files for a patch (I have not yet moved to AS for this reason. waiting for Rails 6 to see if we get something a bit more rounded)

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting the point, but check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775686/how-to-get-url-of-active-storage-image

Comment: @iGian Is the URL generated permanent or for a limited time only ? Maybe my mistake but I thought we couldnt get permanent links to assets with AS. I need dive into AS more thoroughly maybe..

Comment: @Maxence, after your comment I did a test on local storage of my dummy app. I copied the image url, stopped the server and relaunched many times pasting the url into many browsers. The URL is still valid. So, I suppose it is permanent. Also for remote storage. Can you confirm by a similar test?

Comment: @iGian thanks a lot. I was afraid to move to AS from Paperclip due to such limitations. I will do a test on a dedicated bucket with a dummy app and see if I get the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get url of Active Storage image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775686/how-to-get-url-of-active-storage-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file = fetch_your_file

link = rails_blob_path(file, disposition: 'attachment')
```

will return the attachment link

Comment: Note that (to my understanding) this is NOT a link to the file itself, it's a link to a Rails endpoint that will look up the blob and redirect to a temporary signed url for it. This is great for private attachments... not so great for images which will be displayed on the page because rendering the page will trigger a separate Rails request (involving multiple db queries) per each image shown.